# Angular JS ng-grid: How to cancel Editted Row to show back the original values in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid with data and each row has a button for **edit** and **cancel**. When **edit** button is clicked the row data can be edited. So here if I dont want to save the editted data I click **cancel**.When **edit** is clicked I copy the original value of the row with

```
angular.copy(row.entity,$scope.data) ;
```

So now after editting few values I want to cancel the edit and i click **cancel** button. when **cancel** button is clicked I want the grid to show the original value before edit.How can I change.
Please help

Comment: You could temporarily store the old value in localstorage, or if the user cancels reload the original value again from the source. Where is the original data coming from?

Comment: Currently the data is coming from local storage. I am able to store the old value in local storage.The problem is, I am not able to set the old value back to the UI in ng-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to replace the whole row of ng grid in a single line as

```
row.entity = $scope.tempArray
```

which didnt work
Then I tried replacing cell be cell.It worked

I created an array for temporary storage.

```
$scope.tempArray = {
data1:"",
data2:""
}
```

in **edit** function I copied the row data to tempArray as

```
$scope.tempArray.data1 = row.entity.col1;
$scope.tempArray.data2 = row.entity.col2;
```

in **cancel** function the row data is set back to original as

```
row.entity.col1 = $scope.tempArray.data1;
row.entity.col2 = $scope.tempArray.data2;
```